# Comparing iterative methods for linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis

For a tridiagonal matrix of the from

\begin{bmatrix}
a & -b &   \newline
-b & a & -b \newline
  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \newline
  &        &    &    & -b \newline
  &        &   &-b      &  a
\end{bmatrix}

with $a \geq 2b > 0$ I would like to compare, in funtion of $a$ and $b$, the convergence of the Gauss-Seidel method and the Steepest Descent method. But how to do such a comparison if the information about Gauss-Seidel convergence is given by is spectral radius and the information about the Steepest Descent convergence is given by the ratio between the largest and the smallest eigenvalues?

Comment: You'll want to see http://www2.cs.cas.cz/semincm/lectures/2007-05-04-ng.pdf for instance.

Comment: Seems a little bit strange to use Gauß-Seidel or steepest descent, if there is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm...

Comment: This is a tridiagonal symmetric Toeplitz matrix. There are explicit expressions for its eigenvectors and eigenvalues. For example, they are in Iserles' A First Course in the Numerical Analysis of Differential Equations. Is this for a course you are taking?


Comment: Paul is correct, one can relate the characteristic polynomial of a tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix with the Chebyshev polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question, and I happen to have thought about it. Several comments pointed out that for tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix there are other better algorithms; that's true, but it does not answer the question.

I think the confusion comes from the statement "Gauss-Seidel convergence is given by its spectral radius", which is incorrect. Gauss-Seidel convergence depends on the spectral radius of a new matrix $L^{-1}R$ where $L-R = A$, for solving $Ax=b$. It is hard to estimate the spectral radius of $L^{-1}R$, but I am pretty sure that it is related to the condition number of $A$ (the ratio between the largest and the smallest eigenvalues).